# How to use Ng-repeat within controller not in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

According to the below json. If I call this scope in controller, I am getting output :

```
[{"code":"USD","value":"0.00670000"}].
```

I want to get only `value` but within controller I want to do. Does anyone help on this?

```
{"text":[{"code":"USD","value":"0.00670000"}]}
```

Comment: You can't. Which do you use, angular 1 or 2?

Comment: angular 1. then how to get only value: in controller?

Comment: Voting down for not ralating about `ng-repeat` what title mentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure javascript,

```
var myObject = {"text":[{"code":"USD","value":"0.00670000"}]};
console.log(myObject.text[0].value);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/q5arbc1L/)**

Comment: thanks machan, it's working, I only used text[0].value, before I forgot to add [0] during my development.

Comment: ya, but I can do it after 6 minutes in stackoverflow. :)